# Saving changes made with Google Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-inspector

I'm trying to access page(s) on a website.  The pages are loaded via a ribbon navigation across the top of the page (which is always present), which then loads the data in a div container below.

The ribbon/navigation bar SHOULD allow me to scroll left and right - to access other links, and thus other pages - but the scroll button isn't appearing.  I can overcome this problem by using Developer Tools and making the navigation bar much wider (editing the width attribute), thus revealing the links that otherwise remain hidden.

Problem: when I change the CSS to allow access to the 'hidden pages', and then click to load a new page (or new set of data, rather), the new page is loaded, and the navigation bar reverts to its shorter, original state.

Is there any way of preserving my change to the page's CSS?

This is NOT my website.  I have contacted the owners, but they have not answered yet.

Comment: AFAIK no, you'll have to use an extension like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and add CSS rules that override the page. Or make your own.